# Angular: How to make Class Property(variable) Constant That it should not lost data once component reloads

Tags: angular, oop, rxjs

So what I am doing is I am saving the Id of data in local storage so I can send it to the other component because when I go to the other component the data is lost and it shows undefined. I have tried it with rxjs as well. My question that when my data coming from service I want to save it in variable and make it constant while the component reloads in ngonit. So using rxjs I can send this data to various components.

```
 export class AppComponent {
   title = 'promisefitness';
   data:any;
   constructor(private _UserService:UserService, private _RxJsService:RxjsService) {
      ngOnInit(): void {
      this._UserService.Login(UserData).subscribe(DataComingFromBackEnd=>{
      this.data=DataComingFromBackEnd._Id;
 })
 this._RxjsService.SendData(this.data);
   }

 }
```

Now Here I have Declared the data in the class and I want that data should store the response coming from the backend permanently even if the component reloads. Then I can send this data anywhere to another component using Rxjs.

Please Guys Help me . Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want data to persist after reload you need to use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), keep in mind that it does not retain the data permanently and there are certain limitations, I recommend reading about it a little bit first.

With that being said there are two basic commands that allow you to use `localStorage` which are: `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.getItem()`.

Here's a modified version of your code that works:

```js
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   title = 'promisefitness';
   data:any;
   constructor(private _UserService:UserService, private _RxJsService:RxjsService) {}
   
      ngOnInit(): void {
      this.data = this.getDataFromLocalStorage('myData');
      if (!this.data) {
         this._UserService.Login(UserData).subscribe(DataComingFromBackEnd => {
          this.data=DataComingFromBackEnd._Id;
         this._RxjsService.SendData(this.data);
          this.saveDataToLocalStorage(this.data);
       })
      } else {
       this._RxjsService.SendData(this.data);
      }
     }
   
   saveDataToLocalStorage(data: any): void {
    const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data)
    localStorage.setItem('myData', stringifiedData);
   }
   
   getDataFromLocalStorage(dataKey: string): any {
    const data = localStorage.getItem(dataKey);
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    return parsedData;
   }

 }
```

Keep in mind that `localStorage` only saves data as strings, so if you want to save an object there you need to stringify it first and parse it when you retrieve that data, as shown in the example.

Comment: Thanks Brother for the Help. But brothere there is no other way except local storage? I feel Local Storages are unsafe.

Comment: The only other way is cookies, but there's bigger size limitation on cookies and it's left fit for saving raw data. LocalStorage is not safe because nothing on the front end is safe, as a rule of thumb - most security issues should be done on the backend alone. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: that what my concern is that saving tokken or id on local storgae does it can cause security issues? . But there should be another way that when the data comes from backend i can store it in a variable and make it constant so on ngonit() the variable dont lose its data and value.

Comment: And Bro i am using restful apis that is why its stateless no chance for saving states (or data or strings on to backend)

Comment: Saving it on localstorage is not a security issue

Comment: Bro can you send me SS here because I dont understand that link I want to accept your answer